# can not find module webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

when I run command npm run start
then it gives an error that is

[image]

webpack config is

```
  "name": "frokify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "frokify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "Rizwan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you already ran `npm install` ?

Comment: yes i have already ran npm install

Comment: show your package.json too.

Comment: thanks for contribution but i have solved this problem

Comment: You can answer your own question, it may help other viewers :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have webpack added into your `package.json`. Look for **webpack** foder under **node_modules**. If it is not there try  `npm install` before you try `npm run start`